# Opencv camera is available ret returns true, but frame is still empty, is there any fix?

Tags: python, opencv

I am new to opencv and tring to capture some pictures from my Logitech c270 webcam.

the code is like this

```
import os
import time
import uuid
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
for imgnum in range(number_images):
    print('Collecting image {}'.format(imgnum))
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    imgname = os.path.join(IMAGES_PATH,f'{str(uuid.uuid1())}.jpg')
    cv2.imwrite(imgname, frame)
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    time.sleep(0.5)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

and it gives me error

```
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[11], line 6
      4 ret, frame = cap.read()
      5 imgname = os.path.join(IMAGES_PATH,f'{str(uuid.uuid1())}.jpg')
----> 6 cv2.imwrite(imgname, frame)
      7 cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
      8 time.sleep(0.5)

error: OpenCV(4.8.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp:787: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'cv::imwrite'
```

saying that frame is empty.

i have tried

```
# detect all connected webcams
valid_cams = []
for i in range(8):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(i)
    if cap is None or not cap.isOpened():
        print('Warning: unable to open video source: ', i)
    else:
        valid_cams.append(i)
```

my camera is working fine and the camera

```
index (0)
```

is right
tried to print 'ret' returns true, but to print 'frame' is always None.

any ideas how to solve it? Please help me.

Comment: The camera needs some delay to initialize properly I guess

Comment: what makes you think `ret` were true? you never test or print it. the sleep() there is also an issue. it causes the GUI to freeze for that time, every time.

Comment: @toyotaSupra no it should not. it's correct where it is. you need to at least begin to understand the code before you can make reasonable suggestions.

Comment: @NadirBelhaj *no*, it does not. videocapture doesn't work like that.

Comment: Your code is working.  But you have to write for timelapse for every 5 second or whatever.